# MATLAB finding roots, and @ operator

Tags: matlab, root

```
x=1;
f=@(x) x^3 - (5/x^2)-4*sin(x)-2;
fzero(f,x)
ans =

    1.9227
```

I am supposed to find the root of the equation, x^3 - (5/x^2)-4*sin(x)-2, and the above code is the solution for it.

I don't understand the general mechanism of this code.

(1) What does @ operator do?

I know its something like function handle, but I don't understand what function handle is.

(2) How does it work when it includes x in the parenthesis?

(3) How can there be a function fzero(), when I haven't made a script for fzero()?

(4) why are there two variables inside fzero()?
I don't understand that the variable 'f' does there

(5) Why did it declare x=1 in the beginning?

Please consider that I am pretty much new to MATLAB, and don't know much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f = @(x) ...` is the way to declare an anonymous function in MATLAB, actually not very different than creating a function normally in MATLAB such as `function output = f(input) ...`. It is just the pratical way especially when you are working with mathematical functions.

`@(x)` defines that `x` is the variable of which is the same as f(x) in mathematics. `fzero()` is MATLAB's existing function to calculate the `x` value for f(x) = 0 which means calculating roots of defined funtion. Giving your x a real value at the beginning does mean the starting point to find the root. It will find the roots greater than 1 in your case. It will be very clear for you when you read [existing documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html) of MATLAB.

**Edit:**

If you give an interval such as `x = [0 1]` instead of `x = 1`, `fzero(f,x)` would try to calculate roots of f function in given interval, if there is no roots exist in that interval it woud return a `NaN` value.

Comment: @EricKim Matlab's documentation with its own examples is very useful. Good luck! ;)